# Push data into an array (angular js)

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I can't `push` my data into `list` array

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
        $scope.list = ["call naina", "eat food", "do less work", "take meds"];
        $scope.a = false;
        $scope.d = false;
        $scope.k = false;
        $scope.text = '';
        $scope.change = function() {
            $scope.a = !$scope.a;
        };
        $scope.changd = function() {
            $scope.d = !$scope.d;
        };
        $scope.remove = function(x) {
            $scope.list[x] = "";
        };
        $scope.add = function() {

            $scope.list[0].push($scope.text);
            $scope.k = true;
        };

    });
```

---

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.12/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl" >
   <input type=button value="add" ng-click="change()" />
   <input type=button value="delete" ng-click="changd()" />
   <div ng-show="!a && !d" ng-repeat="x in list">
      {{x}}
   </div>
   <div ng-show="d && !a" ng-repeat="x in list">
      <input type="checkbox" ng-click="remove($index)">{{x}}
   </div>
   <div ng-show="a && !d" >
      <input type="text" ng-model="text" placeholder="enter the work" />   <input type=button value="add" ng-click="add()" />
      <div ng-show="k" ng-repeat="x in list">{{x}}</div>
      .
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

change to   `$scope.list.push($scope.text);`
you can have a look here https://plnkr.co/edit/S4wCKnfLQXrWAixM2y9a?p=preview